# Image scaling issue after drag and drop in canvas container using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I have to drag the left container image to the right container in the canvas, but the image after drag and drop in the canvas is cropped off from the original resolution of the image from the left. How do I get the full image inside the canvas?

```js
function handleDrop(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  // e.preventDefault();

  var img = document.querySelector(".image-container .image img.img_dragging");
  console.log("event", e);

  var offset = $(canvasObject).offset();
  var x = e.clientX - (offset.left + imageOffSetX);
  var y = e.clientY - (offset.top + imageOffSetY);

  var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
    width: img.width,
    height: img.height,
    left: x,
    top: y
    // scaleX: 0.25,
    // scaleY: 0.25,
  });

  canvas.add(newImage);
  return false;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL433.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

30 minutes spent :)  Hope this will help you.

You should not use width and height instead you calculate  scaleX, ScaleY based on the height and width of cnavas.

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

  var dragCordX = 0, dragCordY = 0;
  
  
function dragstart_handler (ev) {

console.log(ev.target.src);

fabric.Image.fromURL(ev.target.src, function(myImg) {

// here you can see how we can get height width of canvas and selected image. 
console.log(myImg.width, myImg.height, canvas.width, canvas.height)


let scaleX = (canvas.width-100) /myImg.width; 
let scaleY = (canvas.height-100)/myImg.height;



 var img1 = myImg.set({ 
 left: dragCordX,
 top: dragCordY ,
 scaleX:scaleX, 
 scaleY:scaleY});
 canvas.add(img1); 
});


}


canvas.on('dragover', async (options) => {
    dragCordX = options.e.layerX;
    dragCordY = options.e.layerY;
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color:silver;
}
canvas {
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>

<h4>Original Image</h4>
<img draggable="true" width="100px" height="100px" onclick="dragstart_handler(event)" ondragend="dragstart_handler(event)" id="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL433.jpg" alt="">
 <div class="dropp">
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
</div>
```